# Collapsing tablayout when scrolling recycler view in a fragment of viewpager

Tags: android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have 2 layouts below:

layout 1:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        style="@style/CustomTabLayoutFavoriteFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

, and in my viewpager, my fragment's layout below

layout 2:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:measureAllChildren="true">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/high_margin"
                android:visibility="invisible">
                <!--i have some components in here-->
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabAddBoard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

(my layout 2 is wrapped in a coordinator layout but when i paste in here, it's not visible, i have no idea)
My question is : I want the tablayout in layout 1 to collapse when my recycler view in layout 2 scroll down. If I setup like 2 layouts above, whenever i swipe down the fragment, the tablayout collapse then(when my recycler view has no item or has some items). So, how can i achieve my goal?

P/s: please apologize for my bad english ^^